# Possible to provide an entire document to Update By Query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I would like to search for a document that is stored in ElasticSearch based on it's fields and overwrite that entire document with a new version.  I am new to ES but from what I can tell I can tell I can only use Update if I am searching for a document by it's ES assigned `_id`, so I was hoping to use Update By Query to do this.  Unfortunately, it appears that if I use Update By Query, then I need to provide a script to update the fields I care about.  Something like below:

```
POST my-index-000001/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.count++",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user.id": "kimchy"
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that my document has dozens of fields and I don't know which of them will have changed.  I could loop through them and build the script, but I'm hoping there is a way to simply provide the document that you want and have anything that matches your query be overwritten by that document.  Is this possible with Update By Query?  Or is there another way to match on something other than `_id` and perform an update?

Answer (score 0):

You question is not entirely clear, are you trying to update the whole document for a for a given id? If yes, you can simple overwrite the exiting document with the put call:

PUT index-name/_id

This will overwrite the existing index so make sure that you are sending the complete document in your PUT call and not just the field that have changed.